# Does every windows service calls its executable main function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services

I have a very basic question about windows services, I have this `main` function which install I can use it to install my service, And also there are some configuration data that are loaded inside main function:

```
int 
wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    // it reads config and fill a global struct.
    ReadConfig();

    // if command == 'install'
    install_service();
}
```

and here is the service main function:

```
void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
   // this method retrieves the global config object.
   auto config_data = GetConfigData();

   // service stuff
}
```

and here is another function which is called in my `wmain` function if it is run without any arguments (argc = 0 !):

```
bool
ServiceRunAsService()
{
    static const SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY table[] = {
        { SERVICE_NAME, ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    g_hStopService = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    return StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(table) && GetLastError() != ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT;
}
```

My question is that when windows wants to run my service(after the PC has been shut down and turn on again), Does it call my `wmain` function (and hence call the `ReadConfig` function) or call the registered `ServiceMain` function?
I want to point that the `install_service` method, finds the path of executable by `GetModuleFileName` and pass that to `CreateService` and `ScmManager`

Comment: Why not just check?  Output a log message.

Comment: Honestly I found it difficult to log messages in service ! I don't know how

Comment: of course windows call exe entry point. so `wmain`. system have no any knowledge about `ServiceMain` until you not call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when executable is started, no matter for what reason, the exe entry point is called (if process not crashed or hooked before). so in your case always `wmainCRTStartup` (or what is name of your exe real entry point) which call your `wmain`. so yes - your `wamin` will be called every time when your executable file start.

and system simply can not just call `ServiceMain` anyway. it simply don't know it address. and it not registered. when you register exe service you register the command line for your service, but not any exported name inside exe. your executable became service and register `ServiceMain` only after `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`, which must be called from your `wmain`

even in case dll form service which work with `svchost.exe` - you register exported function which must be called from your dll as service entry point, or `ServiceMain` by default. but anyway even in this case first your `DllMain` (dll entry point) will be called (if exist). in case exe - entry point is mandatory and always will be called

Comment: So in  the end my executable is called without any arguments which then lead to `ServiceRunAsService` being called (which of course gets called when argc == 0) ?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff - this depend from how you register your service via `CreateService` - what is in *lpBinaryPathName* (or *ImagePath* in registry)- service actually can have and not empty command line. if you mix exe for normal start and work as service - you need analyze command line, detect that you run as service and call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`. if your executable design run only as service (you register it via another app) - you unconditionally call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`. anyway - you became service only after `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` call and `wmain` always called on start

Comment: I give the path of executable to `CreateService`'s _lpBinaryPathName_

Comment: @Rachmaninoff - this not change main point. you can use as now empty command line. or some special, for indicate that you run as service. in `wmain` you based on command line or call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` or do another tasks, like register/unregister

Answer (score 2):

When the OS executes your EXE, it calls your EXE's entry point, which then calls your code's `(w)main()` function. When running as a service, your code must call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`, which loops on processing messages from the service controller and calls your  `ServiceMain()`.

Comment: No, the OS will definitely **not** call `main`. The OS will call whatever is specified as the entry point in the PE header. That is not `main`, simply because it doesn't even have the correct signature. Unclear, why this was upvoted. It is *blatantly* wrong, and doesn't acknowledge, that this question is asking about Windows Services, not just any old application.